# when unmarshaling from a schema the order of a sequence matters in jaxb

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I have this schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="foo">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="oneBar" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="twoBar" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

When I try to unmarshal this

```
<foo>
  <oneBar>1</oneBar>
  <twoBar>2</twoBar>
</foo>
```

it works 
but when I try to unmarshal this xml:

```
<foo>
   <twoBar>2</twoBar>
   <oneBar>1</oneBar>
</foo>
```

I get an excelption because it cares about the order
If I try to unmarshal the same xml without using a schema it works in both cases
Any ideas?

As Strawberry pointed out if you replace the xs:sequence with sc:any order wont matter, does any of you know what annotation I need to put in my class so it will generate the xs:any schmea

Found solution by creating the class from the xs:any schema 
You just need to annotate your class with XmlType and set the prop order to be nothing, see:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(name="foo",propOrder={})
public class Foo {
    @XmlElement
    public String oneBar; 
    @XmlElement
    public String twoBar;
}
```

Comment: What are you looking for ideas for?  The contents of your post are true, but I can't find a question in there.

Comment: my question is how to prevent this?
i thought is was implied but I see I was wrong, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sequence requires elements be in order e.g. [from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp) page:-

> The  indicator specifies
>   that the child elements must appear in
>   a specific order:

When unmarshalling without a schema you are effectively not validating the XML.

If you want your schema to NOT require a specific ordering then the following should do that:-

```
<xs:complexType name="foo">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="oneBar" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="twoBar" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

Approaching it from the Java annotation point of view. If I have a Class called `Test` with two string fields `test1` and `test2`, the annotations would be:-

The ordered case e.g. using `<sequence>`

```
@XmlType(name="",propOrder={"test1","test2"})
@XmlRootElement(name="test")
public class Test
{
   @XmlElement(required=true)
   private String test1;
   @XmlElement(required=true)
   private String test2;
}
```

The un-ordered case e.g. using `<all>`

```
@XmlType(name="",propOrder={})
@XmlRootElement(name="test")
public class Test
{
   @XmlElement(required=true)
   private String test1;
   @XmlElement(required=true)
   private String test2;
}
```

Comment: so how can I specify this Foo class in a schema that doesn restrict specific order?

Comment: nice, is there a way to make the schema generator using the generateSchema function to create a schema with the xs:all element?
This above schema was autoGenerated, maybe I should Annotate my class different...